# Investigate handle leak in .NET application exclusively from memory dump

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, handle

I have to investigate a handle leak that occurred in a .NET application and only have a memory dump at my disposal. I cannot do any live debugging or monitoring.

I openend the dump file in Visual Studio 2015, .NET Memory Profiler and Windbg. I can list the 100k open handles in Windbg, from which most are Thread handles:

```
0:000> !handle 0006aaf8 f
Handle 0006aaf8
  Type                   Thread
  Attributes         0
  GrantedAccess              0x1fffff:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         Terminate,Suspend,Alert,GetContext,SetContext,SetInfo,QueryInfo,SetToken,Impersonate,DirectImpersonate
  HandleCount  3
  PointerCount 5
  Name                 <none>
  Object specific information
    Thread Id   1f24.1ce1c
    Priority    10
    Base Priority 0
```

After that , I am stuck. I don't know what to do with this thread ID "1f24.1ce1c", which doesn't seem to match anything in !threads (74 threads total). I don't see anything suspect regarding my managed memory either. Some guides suggest using !htrace for further investigation, but if I'm not mistaken, that only works when attaching to a running process.

I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: A handle leak is not a critical bug. Why can you not profile a debugging or otherwise instrumented build and look for handle leaks? Certainly it is unlikely that a handle leak triggered a crash, unless you are leaking handles like *mad*, in which case it would be rather easy to reproduce the problem in a debug build.

Comment: You say that they're thread handles. Who is creating the threads? Why can't you interactively debug the code that is responsible? Is it not code that you've written or have access to?

Comment: You could try to run [Debug Diagnostic Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) as well to pin-point the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Cody Gray, it is my code, but I can't reproduce the bug. It occurs in production and I am not allowed to access the client's environment. I can ask them to generate memory dumps, which is what they did. Igor, I will try Debug Diagnostic Tool, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: By the way, I don't think a "thread" handle is necessarily a handle to a thread. The denomination is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at native handles, I guess the Thread ID you look at are native ones as well. In your example 1f24 will likely be the process ID that you can also see typing a pipe '|', and 1ce1c the native ThreadId that won't be the same as the managed ThreadId shown by !threads. You might to see if that ThreadId matches a still living thread running '~' command.

Without enabling handle tracing to use !htrace, following on the native track will be complicated. DebugDiag could help as other suggested, and impacting less as handle tracing as it's just about hooking allocation functions.

Otherwise I would recommend to try to look for some clue on the managed side if you believe that could be related to your .NET code. Can't you relate this native thread leak to a managed objects leak? A !dumpheap -stat doesn't show you a high number of System.Threading.Thread, System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext, System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow or such? If you can relate such managed object relationship to your native handle leak, at least you might be able to track the GC references of those objects (!gcroot ) to get more clues.